# contract signing via eSign key

Tags: flutter, google-apps-for-education

Сreating mobile application(flutter) for private schools to automate documentation in Kazakhstan. The question is: How to implement contract signing via eSign key for mobile application? eSign key is used in Kazakhstan to sign official documents.
We have official SDK from government agencies, do not know is it useful information

We do not have any ideas

Comment: check out this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/esign_plugin